# How to make unreachable code warnings to be shown as errors in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, tsconfig, typescript-eslint

I've configured `"allowUnreachableCode": false` in project's `tsconfig.json`, the following code will show a warning in VSCode:

```
const fn = () => {
  return
  //  no-unreachable warning
  console.log()
}
```

How to make it shown as an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version**

Set the `reportStyleChecksAsWarnings` in VS Code settings to `false`

**Long version**

If you inspect the source code of the VS Code IDE, in particular the [`typeScriptServiceClientHost`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/c538781d7809be33511b0f9079d55b111ce504eb/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/typeScriptServiceClientHost.ts) module, you will find out that the TypeScript diagnostics error #7027 is included in the following `Set` (the comment above it speaks for itself):

```ts
// Style check diagnostics that can be reported as warnings
const styleCheckDiagnostics = new Set([
    ...errorCodes.variableDeclaredButNeverUsed,
    ...errorCodes.propertyDeclaretedButNeverUsed,
    ...errorCodes.allImportsAreUnused,
    ...errorCodes.unreachableCode,
    ...errorCodes.unusedLabel,
    ...errorCodes.fallThroughCaseInSwitch,
    ...errorCodes.notAllCodePathsReturnAValue,
]);
```

This `Set` is then used in the [`isStyleCheckDiagnostic`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/c538781d7809be33511b0f9079d55b111ce504eb/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/typeScriptServiceClientHost.ts#L313) method defined as follows:

```ts
private isStyleCheckDiagnostic(code: number | undefined): boolean {
    return typeof code === 'number' && styleCheckDiagnostics.has(code);
}
```

which, in turn, is used in the [`getDiagnosticSeverity`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/c538781d7809be33511b0f9079d55b111ce504eb/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/typeScriptServiceClientHost.ts#L290) method that determines the severity of the error. As you can see from below, the severity is set to `vscode.DiagnosticSeverity.Warning;`:

```ts
if (this.reportStyleCheckAsWarnings
    && this.isStyleCheckDiagnostic(diagnostic.code)
    && diagnostic.category === PConst.DiagnosticCategory.error
) {
    return vscode.DiagnosticSeverity.Warning;
}
```

Notice that this only happens if `reportStyleChecksAsWarnings` is `true` ([which is](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/c538781d7809be33511b0f9079d55b111ce504eb/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/typeScriptServiceClientHost.ts#L56) by default). Since it is exposed to settings, open the `settings.json` (you probably can do it with the editor, but I prefer it this way) and add:

```json
"typescript.reportStyleChecksAsWarnings": false
```

Restart the host, and voila, the nice squiggly lines are there, and the code is reported as a problem:

[image: test function reporting the error]